# Looping through models content in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to loop through each item in my model in my razor view but I want to group all items together. I then want to loop through each group. Imagine I have a table:

```
ID   GroupNo    GroupName
1    1          Group1
2    1          Group2
3    1          Group3
4    2          Group1
5    2          Group2
6    3          Group56
```

I want to do something like:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupNo) {
    <section>
        <header>Group No is @group.GroupNo</header>
        @foreach (var item in group) {
            <p>GroupName: @item.GroupName</p>
        }
    </section>
}
```

So my output is:

```
Group No is 1
GroupName: Group1
GroupName: Group2
GroupName: Group3
Group No is 2
GroupName: Group1
GroupName: Group2
Group No is 3
GroupName: Group56
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried to give your model data structures that would match what your (at a first glance valid) Razor code expects?

Comment: GroupNo is definitely not an IEnumerable<T> right? I'm asking as you are doing a foreach on it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do using the Linq `GroupBy`.  I'd suggest changing your view to use `@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyModel>>`, which you'd populate like this:

```
var groupModel = MyModelCollection.GroupBy(item => item.GroupNo).ToArray();
return View(groupModel);
```

Then, simply iterate through the group as you wrote, except using `group.Key` instead of `group.GroupNo` to retrieve IGrouping's key:

```
@foreach (var group in Model) {
    <section>
        <header>Group No is @group.Key</header>
        @foreach (var item in group) {
            <p>GroupName: @item.GroupName</p>
        }
    </section>
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, but how to you pass that back to the Controller?

Answer (score 10):

LINQ can help you do that

```
@model IEnumerable<Project1.Models.Group>


@foreach (var item in Model.Select(i=>i.groupno).Distinct().ToList()) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <header>Group No is @item</header>
            @foreach (var grpName in Model.Where(i => i.groupno == item).ToList())
            {
                <p>GroupName: @grpName.groupName</p>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: This logic saved me a lot of time.. Thanks!

Comment: Great way to do this if you need to keep your grouping code entirely in your view.

Answer (score -5):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @{
            String[] name = {"Prashant", "Rishabh", "Zaheer", "Pratima", "Rahul"};
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= 5)
            {
                foreach(var x in name)
                {
                       <p>@i.  @x</p>
                       i++;
                };
                break;
            }
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>

O/p-
1. Prashant

2. Rishabh

3. Zaheer

4. Pratima

5. Rahul
```